# Draw tree of coloured rectangled fixed-length bit-strings

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, trees

I have previously asked in this forum on drawing a chain of coloured bit-strings rectangles. I ended up using this code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 1 pt,
  start chain = going right,
  mpnv/.style args = {#1/#2/#3}{% multi part node vertical  % <---
        rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3,
        minimum width=1em,  inner ysep=1pt, 
        font = \sffamily,
        node contents = {\nodepart{one}  #1   
                         \nodepart{two}  #2
                         \nodepart{three}#3},  
        on chain},
E/.style = {fill=red!30},
O/.style = {fill=cyan!30},
I/.style = {fill=yellow!30},
V/.style = {fill=green!30},
L/.style = {fill=olive!30}
                        ]
\node[mpnv=A/B/C];
\node[E, mpnv=1/0/0];
\node[O, mpnv=1/1/0];
\node[I, mpnv=0/1/0];
\node[I, mpnv=0/1/0];
\node[V, mpnv=1/1/1];
\node[L, mpnv=0/0/0];
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which produces this output.

[image]

I'm trying to produce a similar diagram for trees of bit-strings. The structure of the tree would look like this:

[image]

What would be an easy way of writing this, with colours, in latex?

Comment: You should provide not only code fragment but the MWE and show us what you try so far.

Comment: Right: if you copy the code you posted, it can't compile (and guessing your preamble ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For tree I would use `forest` package:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                shapes.multipart}
\newcommand\mpn[3]{\nodepart{one}   #1
                   \nodepart{two}   #2
                   \nodepart{three} #3}
\newcommand\rsp{rectangle split parts}


\begin{document}
\tikzset{every label/.style = {font=\footnotesize\sffamily\bfseries}}
    \begin{forest}
for tree = {
    rectangle split,    
    rectangle split parts=3,
    draw,
    rectangle split draw splits=false,
    inner ysep=2pt,
    %
    parent anchor=south,
    child anchor=north,
    edge = {semithick},
    l sep=7mm,
    s sep=5mm,
            }
[\mpn{0}{1}{0}, fill=red!30
    [\mpn{1}{1}{0}, fill=orange!30
            [\mpn{1}{0}{0}, fill=cyan!30]
            [\mpn{1}{0}{1}, fill=teal!30]
    ]
    [\mpn{1}{1}{1}, fill=orange!30
            [\mpn{0}{0}{1}, fill=teal!30]
            [\mpn{0}{1}{1}, fill=cyan!30]
    ]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, I didn't bother with nodes' colors. You can/should changes them according to your wish.